# Check for permissions without being asked by the system

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I want my app to check if it has permissions to use the device contacts or not.

This is the code i'm using:

```
- (void)isContactsAutherizedWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL granted))completion {
    self.addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(self.addressBookRef, MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback, (__bridge_retained  void *)self);
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                completion(YES);
            } else {
                completion(NO);
            }
        });
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        completion(YES);
    } else {
        completion(NO);
    }
}
```

But with this code i'm automatically being asked if I want to give permissions. I don't want to be asked, I just want to know if it's has permissions or not.

Anyone has a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three states for permission based access.

1. You have been granted access.
2. You have been denied access.
3. The user hasn't been asked yet.

The first time you open the app and try to access something that requires permission it will ask. No way around this.

If you are given permission then it will never ask again and it will work.

If you are denied access then it will also never ask again and the request will fail.

The user will only be asked once for each system. That is how it has to work.

In this case it is in state 3. So it neither has not doesn't have permission. So the check cannot complete. It has to fall into either state 1 or 2 to be able to work out if the app has permission or not.

i.e. Everything seems to be working correctly here.

Comment: That sucks... Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

well from the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ABAuthorizationStatus):

```
typedef CF_ENUM (CFIndex, ABAuthorizationStatus ) {
   kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kABAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized 
};
```

So check if the status is `kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`
and you are sure that you have the permission, in all the other cases you have no permission either because the user did not accept or because you did not ask for the permission yet